# Time complexity of an algorithm that consists a function in disguise

Tags: loops, big-o, complexity-theory

```
Def Function1(arr):
 for i in range(len(arr)):
  If function2(arr,arr[i]):
     a+arr[i]
return a

Def Function2(arr,i):
 for i in range(len(arr)):
   If arr[i]==i:
     return True 
return False
```

is the time complexity of this algorithm n^2 as the for loop for Function1 executes  for n times and in each iteration function2 is executed when the if statements executes where another for loop runs for n times in the worst case. Hence n*n=n^2

Comment: You have two definitions of `i` in Function2. Which one are you comparing for? Consider using different variable names to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop iterates *|arr|* times (meaning the length of `arr`), and the second one *|A|* times. The time complexity would therefore be ***O(|arr| * |A|)***.

If these arrays have the same length *n*, then yes it would be *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. If they depend on each other in some other manner, you can also simplify and express it in terms of one variable *n*. If you have no such information, then the best you can do is to express the time complexity using both variables.

Comment: Ahh sorry I have made an error it’s not A they both take arr

Comment: @RoboJumble In that case, if this lenght is *n*, then yes, Function1 has a time complexity of *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @RoboJumble Of course, if you know something else about the contents of your array, then it may be possible to count how often your if condition will trigger the early return, and possible reducing the time complexity. But without any such knowledge, n^2 is the best you can claim.